# How to test if an event handler is set in a Marionette.js view?

Tags: backbone.js, event-handling, jasmine, marionette, event-binding

There is a [Marionette.js](https://github.com/marionettejs) view which acts as a login form. The following code sample shows the relevant code parts including an error I already fixed:

```
MyApp.module("User", function(User, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

  User.LoginView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    className: "reveal-modal",
    template: "user/login",

    ui: {
      signInForm: "#signin-form"
    },

    events: {
      "submit #signin-form": "onSignInFormSubmit"
    },

    onRender: function() {
      var self = this;
      var $el = this.$el;

      // [...] Render schema

      _.defer(function(){
        $el.reveal({
          closeOnBackgroundClick: false,
          closed: function(){
            self.close(); // <-- This is incorrect. Do not close the ItemView directly!
          }
        });
      });
    },

    onSignInFormSubmit: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var errors = this.signInForm.validate();
      var data = this.signInForm.getValue();
      // [...] Notify that data has been submitted.    
    },

    hideForm: function() {
      this.$el.trigger("reveal:close");
    }

  });
});
```

I noticed a major mistake in my implementation. In the callback function `closed` of [Reveal](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin) I decided to **close** the *ItemView* **directly** which is **wrong** as you can read in the [documentation of Marionette.js](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/v1.0.4/docs/marionette.view.md#view-close):

> View implements a close method, which is called by the region managers automatically.

**Bugfix:** Instead `close()` should be called on the *region*. I fixed this error.

---

Now I ask myself how can I actually write a **test** which covers the problem. I use [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) for testing. I noticed that the event handler `onSignInFormSubmit` is **no longer called** after I have incorrectly **closed** the *ItemView* and try to **re-submit** the form.

Here is a first draft of the test which unfortunately **does fail** also with the bugfix:

```js
it("should call the submit handler for the sign-in form", function() {
  spyOn(userController.loginView, "onSignInFormSubmit");
  spyOn(userController.loginView.signInForm, "validate").andCallFake(function(params) {
    return null;
  });
  userController.loginView.hideForm();
  userController.loginView.ui.signInForm.trigger("submit");
  expect(userController.loginView.onSignInFormSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Maybe one could also test if the event handler is registered such as:

```
expect(userController.loginView.events["submit #signin-form"]).toEqual("onSignInFormSubmit");
```